# pip install labelme failing because FreeType version 2.3 or higher is required

Tags: python, pip, labelme

I can't install `labelme` because I get the error "#error "FreeType version 2.3 or higher is required."

I did
`pip install freetype-py==2.3`

But I get the error:

```
 "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freetype-py==2.3 (from versions: 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2.0, 2.0.0.post1, 2.0.0.post2, 2.0.0.post3, 2.0.0.post4, 2.0.0.post5, 2.0.0.post6, 2.1.0, 2.1.0.post1, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0)"
```

There doesn't seem to be a version 2.3 of freetype. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download labelme directly through the releases page of their github [here](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/releases).

Comment: Thanks, that worked but do you know what was causing the issue with pip?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while installing labelme library. I runed Anaconda Prompt as administrator and typed "conda install -c conda-forge labelme". After this runed the Anaconda Navigator as an administrator as well. you will have no problem using "labelme" library.